# String sorting without converting to array

Tags: python

I'm solving a problem where I need to specific sort, that I wrote in my function `MyFn`, but result of `sorted` in python is a list. Is it possible to return string without using `join`? 
`sorted(s, key=MyFn)`

Comment: `sorted` returns a list, so no, it's not possible.

Comment: If your string `s` is a `bytearray` then it is possible: `s[:] = sorted(s, key=MyFn)`.

Comment: Why not use `''.join`? Python explicitly provides only two means of sorting, and really, they're the same method. `list.sort`, and `sorted`. That's it.`sorted` is implemented internally as `tmp = list(iterable); tmp.sort(); return tmp`, thus, only one true sort.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible because [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sorted) is designed to return a list.

However, you can use [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to convert it back to a string.

```
s_list = sorted(s, key=MyFn)
s_str = "".join(s_list)
```

If you can not use `.join()`, there is another way but this is a bit tricky and I highly not recommand it. You can use [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#repr) to convert your list to a string, and then thanks to slicing, you can get the letters from this list:

```
s_str = repr(sorted(s, key=MyFn))[2::5]
```

As representation of a list of chars is something like `['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']`, this should work.

Comment: I can't use `join` and I can use sorted only one time :)

Comment: @Bob Why could you not? And please, are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Can't use because it's a task, but I can use python 2 or 3

Comment: @BobNapkin I proposed another way without using `.join()` but this is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to return string without using `join`?

Yes, it is possible, but **it's slow**:

```
src = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dest = ''

for c in src:
    dest += src

print(dest)
```

Or, with `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
src = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dest = reduce(str.__add__, src)
print(dest)
```